# How do I cross join a table with itself for each distinct foreign key?

Tags: postgresql, cross-join

A customer gets to select 1 item from each of their favorite merchants.

There are some combinations of items that are better than others.

```
CREATE TABLE favorite_merchant(
  customer_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  merchant_id INTEGER NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE merchant_item (
  item_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  item_name VARCHAR NOT NULL,
  merchant_id INTEGER NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO favorite_merchant(customer_id, merchant_id)
VALUES (1, 1), (1, 2),
       (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3),
       (3, 3);

INSERT INTO merchant_item(item_id, item_name, merchant_id) 
VALUES (1, 'item 1 name', 1),
       (2, 'item 2 name', 1),
       (3, 'item 3 name', 2),
       (4, 'item 4 name', 2),
       (5, 'item 5 name', 3),
       (6, 'item 6 name', 3);
```

Because there are some combinations that are better than others I am cross joining this table for each of their favorite merchants and then sorting for the best combination.

I know how to cross join for merchant options manually for each of a customers favorite merchants. It looks like:

```
WITH 
merchant_1_options AS (SELECT option_name FROM merchant_option WHERE merchant_id = 1), 
merchant_2_options AS (SELECT option_name FROM merchant_option WHERE merchant_id = 2), 
merchant_3_options AS (SELECT option_name FROM merchant_option WHERE merchant_id = 3)
SELECT * 
FROM merchant_1_options 
CROSS JOIN merchant_2_options
CROSS JOIN merchant_3_options;
```

**But how do I do this dynamically?** Meaning how do something like:
For each **m_id**
IN (SELECT merchant_id FROM favorite_merchants WHERE customer = **$1**)
CROSS JOIN (SELECT option_name FROM merchant_option WHERE merchant_id = **m_id**)

Can this be done in Postgres or do I need to do this in my server language?

Comment: You're close, just need a LATERAL & a subquery for the 'pick best item per merchant' logic. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5L7aQmDbQRKNz9JGKSu5WQ/0

Comment: @AdamKG I'm looking for all possible combinations which is why I did a cross join.